# How to convert signed string to its Binary equivalent in Python?

Tags: python

I am using the itertool function to enter value to a list. The itertool function is taking the value as a str, not as an int. After that, I need to convert the values from the list to its Binary equivalent. The problem arises when I need to convert a negative value e.g. -5. My code is taking the "-" as a str, but I need it to consider it as a negative sign before the following numerical value.Does the concept of unsigned integer come into play?

My code is-

```
L3= list(itertools.repeat("-1",5))

file= open(filename, 'w')

L3_1=[ ]

for item in L3:

       x3=bytes(item,"ascii")
       L3_1.append(' '.join(["{0:b}".format(x).zfill(8) for x in x3]))

for item in L3_1:

       file.write("%s\n" % item)

file.close()
```

Comment: What is the expected result? The absolute value in binary? Some expected inputs/outputs would be useful

Comment: yes, i require the absolute value in binary. if input= -5, then output should be= 11111011

Comment: That's not the binary of `abs(-5)`...

Comment: "how to make an integer iterable" makes no sense. You might want to clarify the title.

Comment: Why would you need to make an integer into a iterable object?

Comment: sorry, i didnt mean to say abs, i meant to say the equivalent binary representation. but at the same time i do not want a negative sign in my result after the int is converted to binary. so i guess, i need 2's compliment.

Comment: @leaf i want to write -1 multiple times, that is why i need to make an integer iterable. but the itertool function is taking it as a string

Comment: Why not just use an integer in the first place? Python doesn't have the notion of types in that way, you can just pass the integer `-1` to `itertools.repeat` or any other itterable. You're probably facing an XY problem though - tell us what you want to achieve instead of what doesn't work with your approach.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i can not pass the integer -1 to itertools.repeat; do not know how to; in my code itertool is taking -1 as a str

Comment: @rrra Just write it as an integer literal there: `list(itertools.repeat(-1,5))`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thank you so much, one part of my problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your problem is and what you want to achieve, so please correct me if I make wrong assumptions.

Anyways, converting integers to binary representation is easily done using `bin`. For example, `bin(5)` gives you `'0b101'`. Now, `bin(-5)` gives you `'-0b101'` - which is not what you expect when being used to binary from other languages, e.g. C.

The "problem" is that integers in python are *not* fixed size. There's no `int16`, `int32`, `uint8` and such. Python will just add bits as it needs to. That means a negative number **cannot** be represented by its complement - `0b11111011` is not `-5` as for `int8`, but 251. Since binaries are potentially infinite, there's no fixed position to place a sign bit. Thus, python has to add the explicit unary `-`. This is *different* from interpreting `-5` as the strings `"-"` and `"5"`.

If you want to get the binary representation for negative, *fixed size* integers, I think you have to do it by yourself. A function that does this could look like this:

```
def bin_int(number, size=8):
    max_val = int('0b' + ('1'* (size - 1)), 2)  # e.g. 0b01111111
    assert -max_val <= number <= max_val, 'Number out of range'
    if number >=0:
        return bin(number)
    sign = int('0b1' + ('0' * size), 2)  # e.g. 0b10000000
    return bin(number + sign)
```

Now, to do what you initially wanted: write the binary representation of numbers to a file.

```
output_list = [1, -1, -5, -64, 0]  # iterable *containing* integers
with open(filename, 'w') as output_file:  # with statement is safer for writing
    for number in output_list:
        output_file.write(bin_int(number) + '\n')
```

Or if you just want to check the result:

```
print([bin_int(number) for number in [1, -1, -5, -64, -127]])
# ['0b1', '0b11111111', '0b11111011', '0b11000000', '0b10000001']
```

Note that if you want to strip the `0b`, you can do that via `bin_int(number)[2:]`, e.g. `output_file.write(bin_int(number)[2:] + '\n')`. This removes the first two characters from the string holding the binary representation.